# Need help defining my own rounding function

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction, homework

First of all: I'm a beginner with *Mathematica*.

1. I'd like to define a function called `Rounding` which does the following:

   - if for $x = n+a, n \in \mathbb{N}, a\in [0,1)$ I have $a < 0.5$ then the function should round down to $n$. Otherwise it should round up to $n+1$.

   I did this:

   ```
    Rounding[x_] := If[x - Floor[x] < 0.5, Floor[x], Ceiling[x]]
   ```

   It works.
2. I'd like to create a list `LIST` of random integers and THEN create a `LIST2` which rounds the elements of LIST with my Rounding function.

   ```
   LIST = Table[RandomInteger[{-10,10}]/2, {i,1,10}]

   LIST2 = Table[Round[...]???
   ```

I tried choosing each element of `LIST` by using `Part[LIST,{k,1,10}]` but I don't get it.

Comment: It is a general question. Do we think that we are here to make somebody's homework?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this instance, I would make your `Rounding` function work just the way the built in [`Round`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Round.html) function does, where it will thread over lists:

```
Round[{1, 1.3, 0.5, 1.7, 2}] === {1, 1, 0, 2, 2}
```

By adding the [`Listable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Listable.html) attribute to `Rounding` you can accomplish the same thing:

```
Attributes[Rounding] = {Listable};
Rounding[x_] := If[x - Floor[x] < 0.5, Floor[x], Ceiling[x]];
```

Now

```
Rounding[{1, 1.3, 0.5, 1.7, 2}] === {1, 1, 1, 2, 2}
```

Then to round `LIST` using this function, you can use

```
LIST2 = Rounding[LIST]
```

**EDIT** to add: If you need to do it the boring way because it's a homework problem (`;)`), you can use `Table` to accomplish the same thing:

```
LIST2 = Table[Rounding[e], {e, LIST}]
```

In `Table` (and `Do` and even `Sum`) you can have the "iterator" (i.e., the last argument) range over the elements of a list directly, instead of having to index into the list, like so:

```
LIST2 = Table[Rounding[List[[i]]], {i, Length[LIST]}]
```

I think the former is easier to read, it's definitely easier to type, and best of all, it can be considerably faster to boot.

Comment: Hi - can I do it without Listable? I'm not allowed to use it yet =/

Comment: Great help, I thank you so much.